# Input cursor color

Tags: html, css, colors, text-cursor

How to change the color of content in HTML input type text while entering some value.
And also the cursor color when it has focus.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Changing the colour when entering content is easy:

```
input:focus { color: yellow }
```

not supported by IE7 and lower. Compatibility table [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Changing the cursor colour specifically is impossible as far as I know. It will usually take on the text content's colour which should be fine in most cases.

Comment: In theory it is possible, but you'd have to write some javascript and you'd have to have a picture of the cursor in each color.  It would be tedious and most likely a waste of time. :)

Answer (score 31):

Use `color` to specify the text color. Use `caret-color` to specify the caret's color.

HTML

```
<input class="examples" />
<textarea class="examples"></textarea>
```

CSS

```
.examples {
  color: gray;
  caret-color: red;
}
```

Comment: This should be the answer now. I know the question is several years old, but this is what you should be using.

Comment: Currently at late November 2019, caret-color is supported by most major browsers. You can find the full stats at https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-caret-color. It is currently supported by Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, iOS Safari, Android Browser, Opera Mobile, Chrome for Android, Firefox for Android, UC Browser for Android and Samsung Internet. This SHOULD be the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

Use modern CSS!

```
input {
    caret-color : red;
}
input:focus {
    color : yellow;
}
```